# Nuxt.js - Unable to output nested array elements in Nuxt.js array

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have json object but I am not able to output the nested arrays and really need some help!

Here is my script tag:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mountains: []
      }
    },
    async fetch() {
      this.mountains = await fetch(
        'https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_2/records'
      , {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-Knack-Application-Id": "appIDhere",
    "X-Knack-REST-API-KEY": "keyIDhere",
  },
}).then(res => res.json())
  //     .then((res) => {
  //   console.log(res);
  // })
    }
  }
</script>
```

and it gives me in my console:

```
{
  "id": "60f648317f54bf001f516226",
  "field_77_raw": {
    "id": "60f6479f6bcca0001e7ebf28",
    "application_id": "60da978576b89a001fbc7e36",
    "s3": true,
    "type": "image",
    "filename": "screenshot20210625at1.38.44pm.png",
    "url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2-assets.knack.com/assets/60da978576b89a001fbc7e36/60f6479f6bcca0001e7ebf28/original/screenshot20210625at1.38.44pm.png",
    "thumb_url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2-assets.knack.com/assets/60da978576b89a001fbc7e36/60f6479f6bcca0001e7ebf28/thumb/screenshot20210625at1.38.44pm.png",
    "size": 2621440,
    "field_key": "field_77"
  },
```

but when I do my loops in my template section I can't the thumb_url:

```
<template>
 <div v-for="mountain of mountains.records">
      {{mountain.id}}
      {{mountain.field_77_raw.url}}
 </div>
</template>
```

I just get a message: **Cannot read property 'url' of undefined**

If I put `{{mountain.field_77_raw}}` I get:

```
{ "id": "60f6479f6bcca0001e7ebf28", "application_id": "60da978576b89a001fbc7e36", "s3": true, "type": "image", "filename": "screenshot20210625at1.38.44pm.png", "url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2-assets.knack.com/assets/60da978576b89a001fbc7e36/60f6479f6bcca0001e7ebf28/original/screenshot20210625at1.38.44pm.png", "thumb_url": "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2-assets.knack.com/assets/60da978576b89a001fbc7e36/60f6479f6bcca0001e7ebf28/thumb/screenshot20210625at1.38.44pm.png", "size": 2621440, "field_key": "field_77" }
```

But don't know how to iterate through this nested array. I think it is an object so possibly I just don't know how to handle an object...

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here is the whole json output https://codepen.io/MikedNZ/pen/JjNrJgV

**Answer thanks @tony19**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="mountain of mountains.records">
            {{mountain.id}}
        </div>
        <div v-if="mountain.field_77_raw">. 
            {{mountain.field_77_raw.url}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON response you posted has 8 array elements without `field_77_raw`, so your template needs to conditionally render that field with [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if).

Also, I don't see the `records` key in the data. If the API response is just an array, you're assigning the response directly to `this.mountains`, so the `v-for` should iterate `mountains` (not `mountains.records`).

```html
<div v-for="mountain of mountains">
  {{mountain.id}}
  <template v-if="mountain.field_77_raw">
    {{mountain.field_77_raw.url}}
  </template>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-display-data-in-list?file=pages/index.vue)